# How can I compare 2 Lists from RxJava observables?

Tags: rx-java, observable, rx-android

I have 2 RxJava observables that return the same type Pojo object. One is from my local database and the other is from my webserver.

Here are my 2 observables

```
Observable<List<Wall>> favsLocal = ThemeApp.getInstance().getRepository().getFavsSingle();
Observable<List<Wall>> favsRemote = RestClient.getClient().getFavorite(WallInterface.FAV_GET, ThemeApp.getInstance().getPrefs().getUserEmail()).map(WallResponse::getWallList);
```

What I am trying to achieve is syncing favorites both ways. So i need to compare the results of the two and anything not in my local database needs to be sent to server and vice versa.

```
    favsRemote
        .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
            return Observable.empty();
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .zipWith(favsLocal,
            (wallListLocal, wallListRemote) -> {
                HashMap<String,List<Wall>> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                List<Wall> wallList = new ArrayList<>();
                for(Wall wall : wallListLocal){
                    if (!wallListRemote.contains(wall)) {
                        wallList.add(wall);
                    }
                }
                hashMap.put("Local", wallList);
                List<Wall> wallList2 = new ArrayList<>();
                for(Wall wall : wallListRemote){
                    if (!wallListLocal.contains(wall)) {
                        wallList.add(wall);

                    }
                }
                hashMap.put("Remote", wallList2);
                return hashMap;
            })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(wallStringHashMap -> {
            for (String key : wallStringHashMap.keySet()){
                if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("Local")){
                    for (Wall wall : wallStringHashMap.get(key)) {
                        wall.setIsFav(true);
                        ThemeApp.getInstance().getRepository().setFavorite(wall);
                    }

                } else {
                    for (Wall wall : wallStringHashMap.get(key)) {
                        RestClient.getClient().putFavorite(WallInterface.FAV_ADD, ThemeApp.getInstance().getPrefs().getUserEmail(), wall.getWallId())
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .subscribe(response -> {
                                List<ServerResponseItem> msg = response.getResponse();
                            },throwable -> {
                                throwable.printStackTrace();
                                Crashlytics.logException(throwable);
                            });
                    }

                }
            }

        },throwable -> {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
            Crashlytics.logException(throwable);
        },()->{
            Log.d(TAG, "syncFavorites success");
        });
```

This is what I am currently doing but just seems like there should be something easier.

Comment: Have you looked at `zip`?

Comment: updated question with current method

Comment: You could use a record (tuple) instead of a HashMap with the two diff-lists. The RxJava part can't be simplified further.

Comment: You're calling `wallList.add(wall)` for remote and local.

Comment: this only gets easier with Kotlin...